# Default home on lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have xperia z2 and recently updated to lollipop 5.0.2.

Now everytime I press the home button it asks me whether I want the simple home or the normal one, it's very annoying. 
I tried to select the default but it's not working.

Comment: It's likely that you have two launchers installed. If you press home, choose one and then press "Always" the setting should stick

Comment: This is the problem, it is not sticking. Next time I press home button, it asks again which launcher I want

Comment: Try uninstalling the other launcher?

Comment: You could try some [default app managers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_540) (also see [Default Homescreen Switcher](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher#group_524) specifically for home-screens, and [Manage Default Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_5) for more alternatives).